# Want to use math in SQL column, but it is not an INT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this row in table "users":

```
id = 1; 
birthdate(date) = 1992-02-12; 
joined(int) = 2000;
```

I want to create something like this:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(birthdate as INT(4)) as birthyear, joined 
FROM 
  users 
WHERE 
  (birthyear - joined >= 20)
```

Can anyone give me a hint/tip? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the function `year()`:

```
select year(birthdate) as birthyear, joined
from users
where year(birthdate) - joined >= 20
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Didn't knew SQL had YEAR() function. Another problem I just solved is that I'm working with postgreSQL. They don't have the function YEAR() but they use: EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE). Thanks again!

Comment: @Mossawi . . . Your question is tagged with MySQL.  Many databases support `year()`.  `Extract(year from date)` is the standard, but I think it is supported by fewer databases.

Comment: I didn't knew postgreSQL does not support YEAR(). Thanks again (:

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function to get the year value. Then to get the result that you want you can use something like the following:

```
select year(birthdate), joined
from users 
where (joined - year(birthdate)) >= 20
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10c7a/7)